# handle when product not found in react

Tags: reactjs

i have dynamic route of products

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';

const Product = (props) => {

    const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
    const product = products.find(product => product.title === props.match.params.title);

    const {
        title,
        image,
        description
    } = product;

    return (
        <div className="product">
            <Container>
                <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <Col lg="8">
                        <img width="100%" src={image} alt={title} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <Col lg="8">
                        <p>{description}</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product;
```

but how to handle when product not find and product is undefined and cannot read property title, image, description of undefined

Answer (score 1):

There are different strategies to handle this.

If you want to show a fallback product:

- Use an empty object as fallback for `product` to get rid of the error message
- Assign default values to the properties of `product`

```
const {
    title = 'title',
    image = 'fallback.jpg',
    description = 'this is the description'
} = product || {};
```

If you want to display a message, that no product was found:

- Check if `product` is `undefined` or `null` before destructuring it
- Return a custom message if this is the case

```
if(!product) {
    return <p>no product found</p>
}

const { title, image, description } = product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
const Product = props => {

    const products = useSelector(state => state.products);
    const product = products.find(product => product.title === props.match.params.title);

    const { title, image, description } = product ? product :{};

    return (
        <div className="product">
        {
              product ? 
              <Container>
                  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <Col lg="8">
                         <img width="100%" src={image} alt={title} />
                     </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <Col lg="8">
                         <p>{description}</p>
                     </Col>
                  </Row>
              </Container>
        : <div>Not Found</div>
        }
    </div>
  );
};
```